# Diagonal triple limit

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $1>f(k+1,n)>f(k,n)>0$ and $0<f(k,n+1)<f(k,n)<1$.

And $f(k,\cdot)\to1, f(\cdot,n)\to0$.

Is there an $f$ for every $0<c<1$, such that $f(x,x)_{x \to \infty}\to c$?

Comment: Off-topic: You may use `$\to$` for getting short right arrows instead of `->`.

Comment: Op has now edited his question, in case it goes unnoticed and this comment is noticed! =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(k,n)=c^{n/k}$ works for the original question.

For the $f(k,\cdot)\to\infty$ version mentioned in a (now deleted) comment, $f(k,n)=2^{k-n}c^{n/k}$ works.